# Linking libudev broke desktop and internet

Tags: unity, xorg, internet, udev

So I linked libudev.so.0 with libudev.so.1(found it being a solution for one thing...) and now my system is broken. I am being booted in tty1. No unity. I removed the link and tried a reinstall of libudev, but... apt-get won't connect to internet. Ping command fails to connect any site. I checked if unity is indeed not working(unity and startx commands) and it really is. startx says that can't find libudev.so.1, as does unity. iwconfig says no wireless extensions for ham0, lo and enp9so, but there is something under wlp8so. So I've told all I got this far... What shall I fo now?

P.S. seems like I need to fix it wth no net and without Ubuntu CD/USB. Becoming scary...o≥O

Answer (score 0):

OK! I just found solution.
First remove the link:
`sudo rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1` (or it was 0 in the end...)
Than this command:
`sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1`

So now my system's working again :)